# Writing a program that will use an xbox controller and a pic to control motors

Tags: controller, pic, xbox

I am looking for advice on where to start with regards to writing a c code program that will use an xbox controller and a pic to activate motors.  Would anyone have advice on where to start?

Thank you,

Comment: Why an XBox controller?  I could think of a number of simpler control mechanisms depending on what you were trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

The xbox controller is a usb hub plus a usb hid device. Now I heard that the PIC24F can act as a usb host, so you'd only need an implementation of the usb hid class and you're almost done.

Comment: That sounds cool... I need to research this some more... this could come in handy for projects... thanks.